# Can a web server be left to work alone without constant monitoring on it?

Tags: linux, security, web-server

Does a web server need to be monitored all the time even after securing it and updating it, or can i leave it to work alone after doing that ??

Comment: It's important to regularly patch the operating system and packages/software on any server. If the server is at all *important*, you'll want some sort of monitoring so you know if it's not working. Beyond that, it's really up to you.

Comment: What about server attacks ?? i used to have a long list on my log files, i have had a good security but kept getting those attacks.

Comment: Those sorts of automated attacks are exactly why regular patching is important. They're intended to exploit known holes in old, unpatched software.

Answer (score 2):

There is a wide variety under *web servers*. If you have a simple HTTPd serving static pages, only HTTP/HTTPS allowed on firewall, you can probably manage with automatic updates on your operating system and server software.

If you have any Web Applications, this gets more complicated. PHP could be updated using the methods built-in to your distribution. There are CMSs with and without automated updates. The more plug-ins and custom scripts you use, the more likely you end up having something unpatched.

By adding some Web Application firewall and Intrusion Prevention System you may reduce the time you'll notice any anomalies. Even with most patched systems something will happen sooner or later. Nowadays you must be prepared for that by planning both detection and recovery.

My short answer would be: you can't simply leave it unmanaged.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to update your server daily with security patches. You can do that automatically by setting your update command in SU's crontab.
In addition you can use some statistics software like [Netdata](https://my-netdata.io/) in order to monitor your server.